# Cloudflare wordpress is stuck on refresh settings page

Tags: wordpress, cloudflare

I install cloudflare in wordpress, I get:

[image]

it stuck in refresh, how to fix it? my wordpress version is 4.6.1, and cloudflare plugin version is 3.1.1

**update**

I check php-fpm error log, not any error, and when it stuck, my chrome console show:

```
 action @ 20:23:44.660 CONFIG_FETCH 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.842 CONFIG_FETCH_SUCCESS 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.845 CONFIG_UPDATE_BY_KEY 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.849 INTL_FETCH_TRANSLATIONS 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.856 USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.860 ZONES_FETCH 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.864 @@router/TRANSITION 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:44.866 @@router/UPDATE_LOCATION 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:45.259 INTL_FETCH_TRANSLATIONS_SUCCESS 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:45.262 APPLICATION_INIT 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:45.951 ZONES_FETCH_SUCCESS 
compiled.js?ver=3.1.1:28  action @ 20:23:45.976 ZONE_SET_ACTIVE_ZONE
```

Comment: may be,3.1.1 is not compitable with 4.6.1

Comment: 3.1.1 is compatible with 4.6.1

Comment: @Thellimist So,Why this happen is it internet connectivity issue?

Comment: @VasimVanzara that's possible. It also might be another issue.

Comment: @asullaherc Please check you brower internet connection speed.In other case please check console of browser.

Answer (score 0):

Install either CloudFlare Flexible SSL WordPress plugin or WordPress HTTPS plugin. Many WordPress users are using these plugins to resolve redirect loop issues in WordPress and to make the transition to https:// easier.

**Note:** These plugins were not created by CloudFlare.com and we do not provide support for questions related to these plugins. If you have questions or issues related to using either one of these plugins, please direct your concerns to the plugin author.

**refer link for full guideline :**

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203487280--How-do-I-fix-the-infinite-redirect-loop-error-after-enabling-Flexible-SSL-with-WordPress-